# Wordpress how to remove default wysiwyg editor from custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, wordpress-admin

How can i remove this default editor block [visual | text] of my custom post-types because I create my specific custom fields.

[image]

Thx ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends how you've created your cpt. If you have manually created it using code, then in the argument section where you `register_post_type` you get to define which field(s) you need your cpt to include. So you could simply remove the support for `editor`, so it'll no longer show the classic editor.

```php
'supports'  => array('title', 'excerpt', 'editor', 'thumbnail');
```

Replace it with the following code (if you need just the title field):

```php
'supports'  => array('title');
```

This will remove the excerpt field, the classic editor and also remove the support of feature image for your cpt.